# Call form variable in access query

Tags: ms-access, variables

I have a text box on a form called

```
txtNID.
```

I want to use the value entered into this text box as a column in my query such that it would have the same effect as entering

```
NID: "1"
```

I tried using

```
NID: [Forms]![frmAddCorrespondence]![txtNID]
```

But it doesn't work. The query contains one column called CustID and I want a second column to contain the value of the txtNID textbox.

I also tried setting a function to define a variable for the column but my VB is so bad I just keep going around in circles! Here's what I did:

```
Public Function FrmNID()
varNID = Me.txtNID.Value
End Function
```

Then set the query field as =FrmNID() but it didn't work!

Could really do with some pointers! 
Thanks, Rob

Comment: Is the form open when you run the query? Is the field really named txtNID? Have you declared a parameter for it (it usually works without one, but it works more reliably with it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should. I have just done this on one of my databases and it works find

Forms![frmStaff_admin]![txtCSR_name]

Just remember that your form has to be open!